# Как работает keypad? linux, c , ncurses

Tags: linux, c, linux-mint, ncurses

Написал код вида:

```
int main (void)
{
    initscr ();
    noecho ();
    keypad (curscr, true);

    printw ("%i\n%i\n%i\n", getch (), gethc (), getch ());

    getch ();

    endwin ();
    return 0;
}
```

И при нажатии на стрелку, вместо кода вида `0440` или типа того, он возвращает три символа, которыми закодированы стрелки на линуксе. В чем проблема?

Comment: используй `stdscr`. Адекватное объяснение, почему не работает с `curstr` дать не могу.

Comment: `man keypad` говорит, что при включении вызов `wgetch` (не `getch`) приводит к получению кода нажатой функциональной клавиши. У меня использование `wgetch` при нажатии левой стрелки без включения `keypad` дает символы `68 91 27`, а с включенным `keypad` - `260 260 260` (тройное нажатие стрелки влево). В качестве аргумента там, естественно, `curscr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация на функцию `keypad` явно говорит о том, что код функциональной клавиши будет возвращаться через функцию `wgetch`. Это логично, так как включение `keypad` производится для конкретного окна `WINDOW`, следовательно и читать символы нужно из конкретного окна, для которого включен `keypad`.
*Пример:*

```
int main (void)
{
    initscr ();
    noecho ();
    keypad (curscr, true);

    printw("%i\n", wgetch(curscr));
    printw ("%i\n%i\n%i\n", getch (), getch (), getch ());

    getch ();
    endwin ();

    return 0;
}
```

В данном примере при первом нажатии функциональной клавиши будет выведен ее код, а при повторном нажатии - *escape sequence*.

**Дополнение:**
Функция `getch` начинает возвращать код функциональной клавиши, если `keypad` включить для окна `stdscr`. Возможно это связано с тем, что имплементация *curses* использует `stdscr` в функции `getch` как окно по умолчанию. *Спасибо Andrej Levkovitch за подсказку*.

Comment: ага, плюс хочу добавить, что мой код вверху работает, если вместо `curscr` написать `stdscr`